# Numba parallel time per thread usage in python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, numba

When I run this program in parallel using njit from numba, I noticed that using many threads does not make a difference. In fact, from 1-5 threads the time is faster (which is expected) but after that the time gets slower. Why is this happening?

```
from numba import njit,prange,set_num_threads,get_num_threads
import numpy as np
@njit(parallel=True)
def test(x,y):
    z=np.empty((x.shape[0],x.shape[0]),dtype=np.float64)
    for i in prange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[0]):
            z[i,j]=x[i,j]*y[i,j]
    return z
```

```
x=np.random.rand(10000,10000)
y=np.random.rand(10000,10000)
for i in range(16):   
    set_num_threads(i+1)
    print("Number of threads :",get_num_threads())
    %timeit -r 1 -n 10 test(x,y)
```

```
Number of threads : 1
234 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 2
178 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 3
168 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 4
161 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 5
148 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 6
152 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 7
152 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 8
153 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 9
154 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 10
156 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 11
158 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 12
157 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 13
158 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 14
160 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 15
160 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
Number of threads : 16
161 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 10 loops each)
```

I tested this in a Jupyter Notebook (anaconda) in a cpu with 8 cores and 16 threads.

Comment: this sort of thing is pretty common when working with multithreading. It's likely that there's some overhead associated with each thread accessing the array - e.g. maybe there is a lock that has to be taken by the thread before it can modify the array (idk the details of numba). Or perhaps using more threads than you have cores results in higher overhead with no additional benefits from more CPU power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The code is memory-bound so the RAM is saturated with only few cores**.

Indeed, `z[i,j]=x[i,j]*y[i,j]` cause two memory load of of 8 bytes, one store of 8 byte and an additional load of 8 bytes due to the *write-allocate cache-policy* on x86-64 processors (a written cache line must be read in this case). This means 32 bytes loaded/stored per loop iteration while only 1 multiplication need to be done. Modern mainstream (x86-64) processors can do 2x4 double-precision FP multiplications/cycle and operate at 3-5 GHz (in fact, Intel server processor can do 2x8 DP FP multiplications/cycle). Meanwhile a good mainstream PC can only reach 40-60 GiB/s and a high-performance server 200-350 GiB/s.

There is no way to speed up memory bound code like this in Numba. C/C++ code can improve this a bit by avoiding write-allocates (up to 1.33 times faster). The best solution is to operate on smaller blocks if possible and merge computing steps so to apply more FP operations per step.

Actually, the speed of the RAM is known to increase slowly compared to the computing power of processors. This problem has been identified few decades ago and the gap between the two is still getting bigger over time. THis problem is known as the "*Memory wall*". This is not gonna be better in the future (at least it is very unlikely to be the case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "operate on smaller blocks"? Can you give me an example on how this simple problem can be done in such a way?

Comment: In your specific example, I mean smaller array (because there is no way to use the cache efficiently without more computation). Assuming you have other operation, then you can fuse them if possible. Generally the dependency often prevent you to operate at the same granularity and operating at the granularity of a block (eg 128x128) help to better use caches. A good example of the benefit of blocking is optimized (parallel) matrix multiplications or optimized (parallel) stencils (for the second you can find this in research papers).

Comment: If I use smaller array, the parallel algorithm would not be efficient cause too much overhead from threads. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, assuming a small bock is computed in parallel (or only one small array and no blocking). Generally, a good strategy is to split the work in many blocks and distribute the blocks amongst the threads. The code looks like a prange loop operating over the block with an inner loop computing the items of the block (so each block is computed by only 1 thread). The best granularity of the block is dependent of the algorithm and the target platform. Note that not all code can benefit from blocking though it is quite frequent.

Comment: In fact, modern CPU architectures are hard to efficiently program because cache are (too) small, the overhead of multithreading is quite big and processors start to have a lot of cores nowadays (at least for server) and the main RAM is painfully slow compared to the overall computing power. It makes (efficient) parallel processing much more complex because people should care about both caches and multithreading while mitigating overheads for codes to scale well.

Comment: Can this be done with numba (split the work in many blocks and distribute the blocks amongst the threads) and how? Numba auto-parallelize the algorithm with prange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245927/discussion-between-abzanmaster-and-jerome-richard).

Comment: @ABZANMASTER: "cache-blocking" is the optimization technique you should read up on.  After looping over some data, loop over it again while it's still hot in cache, instead of moving on to fresh data.  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/cache-blocking-techniques.html . Obviously this is easier said than done for some problems, or has tradeoffs.